# O que significa '2>' e '&>' em Bash?

Tags: bash

Estou começando a estudar Bash e enquanto analisava alguns códigos no Github, me deparei com os seguintes trechos para criação de um theme:

```
which rbenv &> /dev/null || return
$(node -v 2> /dev/null)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
which rbenv &> /dev/null || return
$(node -v 2> /dev/null)
```

O [`which`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_which.htm) obtêm o caminho de `rbenv` e redireciona o [*stdout*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluxos_padr%C3%A3o#Sa.C3.ADda_padr.C3.A3o_.28stdout.29) e [*stderr*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluxos_padr%C3%A3o#Erro_padr.C3.A3o_.28stderr.29) para `/dev/null` com `&>`, ou `||` retorna a execução de `node -v` e redireciona para [*stderr*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluxos_padr%C3%A3o#Erro_padr.C3.A3o_.28stderr.29), `2>`.

Onde:

- `which`: Obtém o caminho de um arquivo.
- `&`: Símbolo usado para especificar um [descritor de arquivo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descritor_de_arquivo), quando não há um descritor, redireciona para [*stdout*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluxos_padr%C3%A3o#Sa.C3.ADda_padr.C3.A3o_.28stdout.29) e [*stderr*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluxos_padr%C3%A3o#Erro_padr.C3.A3o_.28stderr.29).
- `>`: Usado para fazer o redirecionamento.
- `/dev/null`: Local para onde será redirecionado, nesse caso o [buraco negro](http://pt.wikipedia.org/?title=/dev/null).
- `2>`: Redireciona as mensagens de erro para `/dev/null`.

Para mais informações [`TLDP - I/O Redirection`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).